# git automatic add and remove?

Tags: windows, git, github, command-line

so to add a file I need to run `git add` and to remove a file `git remove`

but this seems to be a very time consuming job if the project has a lot of files that change on my local copy and then the remote repo needs to be updated.

is there some automatic way to sync the local repo with the remote one, like in the GUI version of git? the gui vesion automatically adds new files and removes deleted files

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git add -A`. It works on your entire working copy and stages (adds to the "Changes to be committed" section) all new (not ignored), modified and deleted files.

Answer (score 0):

There are GUIs available that may help you add files in bulk.  I have used [Atlassian SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) with some success.  However there are ways to add multiple files easily from the command line.
You can use wild cards to add multiple files (i.e. `git add CurrentDir/*.c` to add all the .c files in the current directory.  There are more examples of using wildcards in the [git documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add).